# Rename Variable in c#

Tags: c#

I want to change the variable name to the string I entered.

For example :

```
public int MyVariable;
public string Name="MyName";
```

I want Rename 'MyVariable' to 'MyName'.How ?

Comment: `public int MyName`?

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: are you trying to assign value of `Name` to `MyVariable`? thats possible with simple `=`

Comment: That' a very interesting question. If I understrand you as correctly you want to change your varialbe name as dynamicly. Isnt it? If this is true, one big question will be occure that is WHY? :)

Comment: @NitinSawant I want the variable name to be equivalent to the value string variable

Comment: @EyupCanARSLAN . Yes !.The reason is long

Comment: You can't rename a variable but you could create a Dictionary<Key, Value> which will allow you to set your MyName as KEY.Then you would be able to access your value with your specified name => https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't because C# is a strongly-typed language.

See [Types (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/).

> C# is a strongly-typed language. Every variable and constant has a
>   type, as does every expression that evaluates to a value. Every method
>   signature specifies a type for each input parameter and for the return
>   value. The .NET class library defines a set of built-in numeric types
>   as well as more complex types that represent a wide variety of logical
>   constructs, such as the file system, network connections, collections
>   and arrays of objects, and dates. A typical C# program uses types from
>   the class library as well as user-defined types that model the
>   concepts that are specific to the program's problem domain.